# What happens when you do a ToList() on a gigantic table storage table?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I had some really old code somewhere on my application that I accidently triggered:

```
var json = table.CreateQuery<ActionLog>().ToList().ToJson();
```

another suspect is:

```
var action_log_list = await table.CreateQuery<ActionLog>()
    .Where(log => log.StartTime > startTime)
    .AsTableQuery()
    .[...]
```

The problem is that this table is gigantic - probably hundreds of millions.

About the same time I hit this code it took out one instance of my application and that one didn't come back for more then one hour. Even after Restarts.

Now I was actually investigating some **mild** performance problems, so I'm wondering; was this a coincidence or could the code above bring down a table storage - like a 'really long running query' and after that blocking i.e. inserts or reads on that table?

Comment: Shortly said: Yes.

Answer (score 0):

> About the same time I hit this code it took out one instance of my application and that one didn't come back for more then one hour. Even after Restarts.

Based on my knowledge, we could use the [ExecuteSegmentedAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.cloudtable.executequerysegmentedasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Table_CloudTable_ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Table_TableQuery_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Table_TableContinuationToken_) to improve the peformance. The following is demo code.

```
 var query = table.CreateQuery<ActionLog>().AsTableQuery();
 TableContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
 do
   {
      // Execute the query async until there is no more result
      var queryResult = await query.ExecuteSegmentedAsync(continuationToken);
      // to do something
      continuationToken = queryResult.ContinuationToken;
   } while (continuationToken != null);
```

As it is gigantic table, it may still need long time to do that. I don't test it on my side.

But based on my experience, if we want to deal with so huge records, I recommand that you could use [Azure Data factory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-factory/) to do that.